# how can I make template of blogger from PSD files , PSD to XML file

Tags: blogger

I created a blog on blogger.com
I design a template with Photoshop and I'd like to transform it to XML file to make it as blogger template ...

mm what's the solution , can I do this act !
can I generate a xml file from PSD ... 
I don't know ... I read that I can and I saw a blog about this subject ,but I don't remember where !

any help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot export a psd file to XML or (X)HTML. PSD's contain no logical formatting - they are in essence (for the purposes of this explanation) a raster based image.

In order to convert a PSD to XML, you need to code the XML by looking at the PSD. Do you know HTML/XML? If not, this might be a very audacious task.

Perhaps try reading http://www.bolducpress.com/tutorials/from-psd-to-html/

There are some nice tips there

Answer (score -1):

here a site that i have been watching to help with this task 
i too want to the same thing

i hope this helps

http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/how-to-convert-a-psd-to-xhtml/

Comment: Page Not Found

The page you are looking for could not be found.